# $stateChangeSuccess doen't be fired

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have tried to send pageview data to google analytics. And I'm using ui-router on angular.js. ui-router version is 0.3.1 stable.

So I added method `run` to handle `$stateChangeSuccess` but any state changing actions seems not fired that event even when I added parameter `notify:true` at $state.go like `$state.go('ant.written', {userName:userName}, {notify:true});`

I googled this but I couldn't find about this.

Here is `app.run` code snippets.

```
app = angular.module('stocktalkApp', [ 'ui.router',
        'ui.router.stateHelper', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngOnload' ]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$window', function($rootScope, $location, $window){
    $rootScope
        .$on('$stateChangeSucces', function(event){
            if(!window.ga)
                return;
          ga('send', 'pageview', {page : $location.path(), uid : userName});
        })

}]);
```

Comment: looks like you spelled it wrong and are missing an `s`

Comment: oh i'll retype again thank you @sharlieftl

Comment: @charlietfl yes you're right. it works fine now. Anyway, It also works well when I use `$locationChangeSuccess` event instead `$stateChangeSuccess` if someone's code that used that `$stateChangeSuccess` is not working, I think this comment is helpful.